Is there any reason for the ark that holds the Torah to be vertical?
In every synagogue I have have been in the aron kodesh (ark which houses the Torah) stands vertically, with the torah scrolls inside also placed vertically. I would like to know if there is any reason or law which pertains to this. Meaning is this just a standard convention to have the aron kodesh standing vertically, and it could theoretically be laid out horizontally with a(n Ashkenazi) Torah scroll lying inside flat/horizontally, or does it have to be vertical for some halachic or practical/logistical reason?

It's a Halachic issue.
See the Tosafos (הא דעבידא כסיכתא הא דעבידא כאיסתוירא) in Menachot 33a, and the summary of the Piskei Tosafot (ibid).

ואמר כשבניתי הארון הקודש אם נזכרתי הרחבתי לפי מדת ס"ת מיושב וטוב לצאת ידי שניהם ולהניח באלכסון

It seems that the way to place a Sefer Torah in the Aaron Hakodesh - vertical or horizontal - is identical to the Halacha of placing a Mezuza:

Rashi says it should be vertical
Rabbeinu Tam says it should be horizontal

The poskim therefore either suggest vertical or vertical at a slight angle.
As to why the Ashkenazi Sefer Torah is horizontal on the Bima during leining, could be based on a pithy statement (ibid) כשס"ת עומד עומדין וכשיושב יושבין paraphrasing Rabeinu Tam - when the Torah scroll (is visible and) is standing (vertical) everybody stands, when it's sitting (horizontal) everybody sits.

Most Ashkenazi bimot have the Sefer Torah at a slight incline

Halacha is a strong term here. An aron isn't kosher or not. For mezuzah it's a halachic question but for Torah it's a question of kavod which doesn't have to be objective.

+1 Does he mention any idea why?
